# c++ classes linked to each other with std safe pointers (c++)

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, c++11, weak-ptr

I have problem in my project. I believe shared/weak pointers from new c++ stabdards can solve it but its unclear to me how. In book i read about standard library there is no comment on my idea how to use these pointers.

In my application i have `Library` class. This class has internal `vector` of `Book` objects. These objects usually created inside `Library` class, though external code queries `Books` objects from it using functions and uses them later. Each `Book` instance has a public pointer to 'host' `Library` instance.

Sometimes external code deletes `Library` and creates new, but it may still use previously queried `Book` objects from old library. My problem is that `Book` class should drop pointer that no longer valid, so book will not contain invalid pointer to deleted library instance.

It is unclear for me how to implement weak pointers to book class to achieve such behavior.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Library` pointer inside a `Book`?

Comment: Book objects are used in script system and they have to contain that pointer, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

As the `Library` needs to know how to add a book, it needs to know how to get a `weak_ptr` to itself. Luckily there is a helper base class called `enable_shared_from_this` which allows you to do that.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Library;

struct Book {
  std::weak_ptr<Library> host_library;
};

class Library : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Library> {
    std::vector<Book> books;
 public:
  const Book& getBook(size_t index) const { return books.at(index); }
  void addBook() { 
      books.emplace_back();
      books.back().host_library = shared_from_this();
  }
};

int main() {
    auto library = std::make_shared<Library>();
    library->addBook();

    auto book_copy = library->getBook(0);              
    library.reset();                                   // Destroy the library

    auto old_library = book_copy.host_library.lock();  // Try to get a shared_ptr
    if (!old_library)                                  // to the library from the book.
        std::cout << "Library gone!\n";
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xASe1igVE9KgxDfh).

For it to work, `Library` always needs to be created as a `shared_ptr`. You could enforce that by making the constructor private and having a static create function that returns a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think weak pointers are going to help you.

Rather look at implementing the Library class better.  Surely the library should know which books belong to it.  In the event of deleting a library it should clean its memory and update all objects that belong to it.

What happens to the book when the library is deleted?

Rather use `std::unique_ptr`